# How do you store user email or username instead of RID in action types?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-actions

I am trying to store the emails and usernames of users who trigger an action type that modify or creates an object. I can do that for the id already, but am not sure how to get other properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to store username and email of the current user. The easiest way to do that is to follow these steps:

1. In your Workshop Application, create 2 variables using: New variable > String > Multipass attribute > Username [image: Create two variables]
2. Add the two variables as a default value to the fields of your action (here the name of the field is Attachment) [image: Add variables to action field]
3. The username and emails will be filled by default in the form: [image: Action submission form]

This information will be stored in "Entered By" property. As they are multipass attributes, if you display such property in a table, the name of the user will appear. [image: end result]

Comment: You should make sure to turn on the display formatting for multipass ids in the Ontology property configuration. With this enabled, you'll get not only the first and last name displayed in Workshop and Object Views and elsewhere, but also an interactive card on hover with more identifying information like email. This is essential for building workflows with assignment etc so that you can differentiate between people with the same name: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/object-link-types/value-formatting/#supported-value-formatting